# How do I get my writing to be more thrilling?

Tags: creative-writing, style, characters, character-development, writers-block

I started writing not too long ago, but I've been struggling to actually make the readers get into the reading. I've been told that my writings are too "straightforward" or "too direct".

I can't really get *in* my characters head, to understand what they would do or feel in a situation that is mentally overwhelming for them. It ends up being too boring, I need advices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit difficult to tell what you actual problem is without reading one of your stories. Maybe you can ask your beta readers what they would have changed and in what way?

---

Guessing from what little clues you give, I'd assume that one of the following might be your problem:

- You write as if you were the protagonist. The problem with this is that you know what you would want and how you would behave (because all you have to do is follow your own hunches), but for the readers that character will be too intransparent and incomprehensible in their motivations and choices.
- You know where you want your character to go (maybe because it is what you would want yourself), and you are giving their goal to them too quickly and without much hindrance. That will feel satisfying while you write it but seem boring to readers, as it lacks the tension coming with obstacles and disappointment.
- You have little experience in life and/or with other human beings and/or you have difficulty taking on the perspective of others. So every character you write is a variation of yourself, or (if they are not) they are stereotypical cardboard characters without depth.

If any of this applies, there is nothing you can do about your writing except getting out in the world and outside of your head.